# Можно ли увеличить выводимый текст в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Хочу вывести emoji в терминал, но он слишком маленький.
Есть ли возможность увеличить размер emoji?

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Символы - это лишь символы, они не хранят никакой информации о своих размерах, чтобы озвученное в вашем вопросе было возможным.

Размер шрифта можно увеличить лишь в эмуляторе терминала, если он поддерживает данную функциональность.

Answer (score 2):

Если Вам нужно увеличить размер смайлика, то это невозможно, можно только увеличить размер всего текста в терминале(Ctrl + колёсико мыши). Не уверен, что поможет, но Вы можете поискать библиотеку для Python, которая предлагает перечень новых смайлов, возможно, у них будут размеры, которые будут Вам по душе. Хорошего Вам дня!!!